# Geh jedem Streit aus dem Weg!

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase and in which situation can it be used?

> Geh jedem Streit aus dem Weg!

In my opinion this is comparable with the advice:

> Stay out of trouble!

Comment: The *jedem* isn't needed nor common. If you wanted to translate it with *jedem*, you had to say *any trouble*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is comparable and would probably be used in similar contexts. It may be a "life-motto" as well as a phrase a mother says kissing her child goodbye for school.

Answer (score 1):

IMO "stay out of trouble" is not a good match, because staying out of trouble means more than just avoiding arguments or fights with others ("Streit"), but also things like "getting caught shoplifting".